# Can`t get value for Math.Abs(-2147483648)

Tags: c#

here is my code.

```
string strTemp = "";
for (int i = input1; i <= input2; i++)
{
    strTemp = Math.Abs(i).ToString();
    //other stuff here
}
```

when value of input1 is -2147483648 then I get error

> Negating the minimum value of a twos complement number is invalid.

I somewhat get is that that is due to Over flow exception.
But how I can overcome this? Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`+2147483648` is larger than the maximum value of an `int`, which is 2<sup>31</sup> - 1.
Instead, you can use a `long`; its maximum value is 2<sup>63</sup> - 1.

If that's not enough for you; use `BigInteger`.

Comment: So you mean I have to cast int to long like `Math.Abs((long)i).ToString()`

Comment: @SLaks input1 and input2 are always int and supplied in function. Actually I am stuck at syntax how to write?

Answer (score 0):

as @SLaks said

> +2147483648 is larger than the maximum value of an int

you could check this by using `Int32.MaxValue` and `Int32.MinValue`:

```
x = -2147483648
if(Int32.MaxValue <= x || Int32.MinValue >= x) {
    return x;
}
```